# Custom theme typography in mat-toolbar

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material-7

I'm theming my app defining colors and typography. But it's not working for the heading in my app header component based on mat-toolbar. My theme is overridden by default theme css rules for `.mat-toolbar h1`.

**index.html**

```html
    <html>
    ...
     <body class="mat-typography">
            <app-root></app-root>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**_theme.scss file:**

```
    @import '~@angular/material/theming';
    @import 'utils/palette';
    // Plus imports for other components in your app.

    // Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
    // (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
    // hue. Available color palettes: https://material.io/design/color/
    $fem-theme-primary: mat-palette($fem-palette-primary);
    $fem-theme-accent: mat-palette(
        $fem-palette-primary
    ); // NOT USED, same as $fem-theme-primary!
    $fem-theme-warn: mat-palette($fem-palette-warn);

    // Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
    $fem-theme: mat-light-theme(
        $fem-theme-primary,
        $fem-theme-accent,
        $fem-theme-warn
    );

    // Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
    // Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
    // that you are using.
    @include angular-material-theme($fem-theme);

    // Define a custom typography config that overrides the font-family as well as the
    // `headlines` and `body-1` levels.
    $fem-typography: mat-typography-config(
        $font-family: $font-family,
        $headline: mat-typography-level(32px, 48px, 700),
    );

    @include angular-material-typography($fem-typography);

    // Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
    // have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
    // Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
    @include mat-core($fem-typography);
```

**topbar.component.html**

```html
    <div class="topbar">
        <mat-toolbar>
            <h1 class="topbar__logo mat-headline">App Title</h1>
            <mat-form-field
                class="topbar__search"
                appearance="outline"
                color="primary"
            >
                <input
                    matInput
                    data-e2e="topbar-search-input"
                    class="topbar__search-field"
                    placeholder="Søg"
                    (input)="handleSearchChange($event)"
                />
                <mat-icon matSuffix inline="true">search</mat-icon>
            </mat-form-field>

            <div>
                <span class="topbar__current-user">{{ currentUser.name }}</span>
                <a
                    mat-button
                    class="topbar__log-out"
                    href=""
                    data-e2e="btn-logout"
                    (click)="logout()"
                    >Log ud</a
                >
            </div>
        </mat-toolbar>
    </div>
```

Font family is working... But I expect the `<h1 class="topbar__logo mat-headline">App Title</h1>` to have css:

```css
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 48px;
    font-weight: 700;
```

Instead it has the default styling:
css:

```css
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-weight: 500;
```

How can I make ALL Angular Material components (including mat-toolbar) use my own theme?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm facing the same problem : (

Answer (score 0):

Component mat-toolbar deliberately overrides all heading tags (h1 through h6) to "title" typography, which maps to h2.
You can make it show "regular" typography for h1 with:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

.mat-toolbar h1 {
   @include mat-typography-level-to-styles($fem-typography, headline); // where headline maps to h1
}
```

Here are all the mappings, if you'd like to apply the above for other heading sizes:

- headline: h1
- title: h2
- subheading-2: h3
- subheading-1: h4
- caption: h5